# entry point DLLRegistryServer was not found

Tags: dll, com

I'm trying to register a .dll file(`msvcr110.dll`) using `regsvr32`.

But I get an error that says:

```
the module  msvcr110.dll was loaded but the
DLLRegistryServer entry point is not found
```

I have run the command under both System32 and SysWOW64 and I have run my commands with `Run As Administrator`. Could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is telling you that what you are trying to do doesn't make any sense.  Which is accurate, the C runtime library is not a COM server.  Just stop trying to do senseless things.

Comment: Additional useful reference you should read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293574(v=vs.110).aspx. Please consider your options for properly deploying the Microsoft C++ Runtime library. Each option has its advantages and disadvantages. Choose wisely.

Answer (score 0):

`msvcr110.dll` does not need to be registered. `regsvr32` registration is applicable to DLLs that host COM servers only. Such DLLs export `DLLRegisterServer` entry so that it is given a chance to update registry and add registration-specific entries and hence enble discovery of the hosted COM classes. `msvcr110.dll` is used as a dependency DLL directly, not via COM.